# Can I launch an iPad application in a different locale than what iOS uses?

Tags: ipad, internationalization

My iPad 3 is configured in French for the family but I prefer my apps un-translated. Is it possible to force an application to launch in a specific locale? Is it feasible without a third-party tool?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is, unfortunately, not possible with the default install of iOS.

It is always possible that there is a jailbreak hack that allows this, but that would probably fall under the "third-party tool" category.

Comment: too bad. i really don't want to jailbreak the thing but i'm lucky since it came out very recently. Any recommendations regarding the app or you don't know about this kind of things

Comment: @samy, no, I'm sorry, but I don't have any recommendations. A little strange, but my network doesn't allow me to go to the iOS 6.1 jailbreak website so I can't even look around there for you. If you find something that works for you please be sure to update us.